# Showing X-Forwarded window on current machine for mac

Tags: macos, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, xforwarding

If I ssh into a server using `ssh -X unixserver.com`, I can run a command which opens a graphical application and the window will show on my current computer.

I want the same to happen when I ssh into a normal desktop computer (specifically a mac). Like this, `ssh -X mymac.com`. However, when I do this it just loads the window on the remote machine - not my current machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X native graphics isn't X11-based and can't be forwarded.  And nobody can write a third party forwarder because the WindowServer <-> Core Graphics interface is undocumented and deeply tangled (per Jeremy Huddleston, the poor person who maintains XQuartz and has to try to make X11 stuff behave halfway sanely on OSX; check the X11-users@lists.apple.com archives).

Comment: Do you know of any other way to forward graphics on OSX? I'm connecting from a mac to a mac, so doesn't HAVE to be X11.

Comment: You can turn on the built-in VNC server in System Preferences > Internet and Wireless > Sharing > Remote Management > Computer Settings... — but the built-in server is slow and unstable (that is, it has a tendency to crash when used for anything complex).  [Vine Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/) is a popular alternative that works well.  For the client, you can use the built-in Screen Sharing (which is hidden in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Screen Sharing.app`) or install a third party VNC client such as [JollysFastVNC](http://www.jinx.de/).

Comment: BTW, Apple's own Remote Desktop product is little more than a glorified VNC server/client, so you're not actually missing much by going that route.  (And it's also an indication that hooking the WindowServer for remote display is something even Apple won't attempt.)